# How to do getPaths of polygon from the react-google-map?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

Below is my coding:

```
const SiteGoogleMap = compose(
withProps({
googleMapURL: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY}&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`,
loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
}),
withScriptjs,
withGoogleMap
)((props) =>
<GoogleMap
defaultZoom={18}
defaultCenter={{ lat: 3.1314067, lng: 101.6285082 }}
>
{props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} onClick={props.onMarkerClick} />}

<DrawingManager
  defaultDrawingMode={google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON}
  defaultOptions={{
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
      ],
    }
  }}
  onPolygonComplete={(value) => console.log(getPaths())}
/>
</GoogleMap>
```

I'm trying to get the path of the polygon drawn which will give me the coordinates of the paths. But it gives undefined on console.log. Do you guys know why?

Answer (score 2):

Since `onPolygonComplete` event is mapped to `polygoncomplete` of `DrawingManager` class, the `value` parameter represents `Polygon` object:

```
onPolygonComplete={(value) => console.log(getPaths())}
                    ^^^^^
                    polygon object
```

that could be passed into `getPaths` function:

```
onPolygonComplete={(value) => console.log(getPaths(value))}
```

and then the coordinates of the polygon drawn could be printed like this:

```
function getPaths(polygon){
  var coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());
  console.log(coordinates);
}
```

Comment: This gives the result, but my question is polygon means the starting point and ending point should be the same right? In this case it's different for me or am i missing something?

Comment: not necessary for the start and end points to coincide; if they do not, the polygon will be automatically closed

Comment: the polygon get automatically closed, but still the starting array and end are not same, so confused